# Insert rows into worksheet from another workbook?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, vba

I have two workbooks, say: **workbook_a.xlsx** and **workbook_b.xlsx** and both contain different worksheets. Two of those worksheets are already linked by a couple of **VLOOKUP** formulas using a unique key which is the **custid** column. With this setup I can let users enter data in the **workbook_a** and then I can run all my BI on the **workbook_b**. Now, one of the most tedious things I do is search for new high risk customers in **workbook_a** so I can manually add them to **workbook_b**. I would like to do the following:

1. From **workbook_a** lookup **custid** in **workbook_b**.
2. If it exists, do nothing (I already added the customer and the
   **VLOOKUP** formula will take care of updating the
   **cust_risk** cell value).
3. If it doesn't exist, copy the row from **workbook_a** to
   **workbook_b** (maybe even not the whole row but just one cell?).

Is this possible? I'm using Excel 2007.

Comment: Yes, you can do it in a VBA macro, I was whipping one up, but have hit some Excel bug and burned what time I had.  I'll check back later when I have time to see if you still need an answer.

Comment: Thanks @Lance, I will probably need an answer since I have no idea how to do it. I was actually looking to do it with formulas, to make the workbook more "portable".

Comment: @rdrgtz, Formulas are no more portable than VBA, they are both __'in'__ the workbook.

Comment: Thanks @lance, I wasn't aware that VBA resides "in" the workbook.

Comment: Ok, I'm ready to work on this but don't know which cell you want to copy and where you want it to end up.  Throw me the relevant column numbers and names on each sheet and I'll whip something up (I hope).

Comment: @lance I'm abandoning this in favor of migrating the Excel sheet to a PHP/MySQL/AJAX app, but thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can make a VBA macro for this.

I'd create a button, and in the click event, first make sure workbook_b is open, then use the following code to copy the rows where custid is in workbook_a, but not in workbook_b (note that in the end you just end up with a copy workbook_a in workbook_b, so it'd be a lot simpler to just copy the whole data range over).

```
Dim i As Integer, workingCol1 As Integer, workingCol2 As Integer
Dim workingRange1 As Range, workingRange2 As Range

workingCol1 = WorksheetFunction.Match("custid", Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows(1), 0)
Set workingRange1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("AllCustomers").Columns(workingCol1)

workingCol2 = WorksheetFunction.Match("custid", Sheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Rows(1), 0)
Set workingRange2 = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("CriticalCustomers").Columns(workingCol2)

For i = 2 To workingRange1.Rows.Count
   If Not IsError(Application.Match(workingRange1.Cells(i, 1), workingRange2, 0)) Then
    workingRange1.Rows(i).EntireRow.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Rows(Sheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Rows.Count).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
  End If
Next i
```

If you really only need one cell copied over, then you could do it with a worksheet-function, but it'd be a little complicated.

Comment: Nifty script @lance, but like you said, if the result is a workbook copy, then not much use. Also, the fact that it's VBA limits the use to one machine, and I want the function to work no matter where I take the Excel file (unless I'm mistaken and VBA is embedded in the Excel file itself).

Comment: @rdrgrtz,I don't think you get what I'm saying.  What you specified was what wrote, if you don't want it to be just a copy then specify something different.  The VBA is in the file, just like any worksheet-function is in the file, so therefore I assume now you only want a __menu-driven__ solution.  Please verify and clarify your question if you really didn't want to end up with a copy.

Comment: Thanks for the clarify @lance, I did get what you were saying, I just wasn't aware that VBA resided "in" the file. Your solution, as per required, is correct; I guess I just want a conditional copy of just one cell, and not the entire workbook. I'll mark this as answered, sorry for the upset.

Comment: @rdrgrtz, I'll get back to you with a one-cell copy.

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested, another approach would be to first set up a dynamic named range in workbook_a, which covers the area where you permit users to enter data.  Then, use that dynamic named range as the source for a pivot table in workbook_b.

Any changes you make to your data in workbook_a, including new customers, get picked up when you refresh the pivot table in workbook_b.

Note that both workbooks need to be open.

Specifically, when I played around with this, I named my dynamic range in workbook_a as "AllCustomerData", with the data starting in cell A1 on sheet1, and defined the formula for "AllCustomerData" as

```
 =OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,0,0,COUNTA(Sheet1!$A:$A),COUNTA(Sheet1!$1:$1))
```

Next, for the pivot table source in workbook_b, I used

```
 workbook_a.xlsx!AllCustomerData
```

Then, when I built the pivot table, I chose the "Classic Pivot Table layout".  I placed all my fields in the "RowLabels" section of the Pivot table Fields List box, in the order of my fields in the original workbook_a.  You can, of course, order them as you desire -- or only select the field(s) you need.

When I tested this, I did see that if I deleted a customer, refreshed the pivot table, then re-used that deleted customer's CUSTID at the bottom of the source range, and again refreshed the pivot table, that the re-used CUSTID would show up in the pivot table not at the bottom, but in the original position before deletion.  (I hope that was clear!)  I don't know if your business rules permit re-use of CUSTIDs, but be aware of that if you do.

Hope this helps.  The VBA approach of @Lance Roberts is real nice too.  It has an advantage over this pivot table approach of not incurring all that "pivot table overhead".

Comment: Thanks for the answer @f106dart, but not what I'm looking for.